# Tutorial for building a safari HTML5 panorama?

Tags: ios, html, safari, panoramas, virtual-reality

Is there a tutorial out there for building a HTML5 based VR panorama like the one presented in Apple's technology demo? I'm asking because there's very little search results or tutorials on reproducing the VR effect. Here's the link:

[VR Demo](http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/vr.php)

Answer (score 0):

Pano2VR creates awesome navigable panoramas, in both HTML5 / CSS / Javascript as well as Flash. They work on desktop OSes, iOS and Android devices. I've been searching the same thing, hope this helps.

http://gardengnomesoftware.com/tutorial.php

G